# Cannot make divs from json (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

I'm trying to make a list of divs from a json file but when I run the code nothing happens. Please help.

HTML:

```
<section>
    <template>
      <div class="question-box" style = "width: 30vw; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div class="question" v-for="data in myJson"><img class="question-icon" src="../img/consiliu.png">{{data.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
    import json from './json/lista.json'
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                myJson: json
            }
        }
    }
</script>

  </div>

</section>
```

List.json

```
[
{
 "name": "1"
},
{
 "name": "2"
},
...
{
 "name": "9"
}
]
```

This is the json file. I need to see divs that contain text 1,2,3 and so on.

Comment: Just a note, you're running your loop as `<li>` elements, not `<div>`, so your leading text for your question doesn't correlate to what you're trying to achieve with your current code. You also seem to be missing your `:key` prop. I also believe you want to do the import before trying to loop over it as I don't believe your json variable is being hoisted in this case.

Comment: yeah, initially I tried to make it <li>, if I add the key prop it will work?

Comment: Try and see my updated comment. Try and import your json variable before the code part where you are attempting to initialize a loop. I'd also recommend to simply declare an exported const variable to be your json array and import the variable as opposed to the entire file.

Comment: @tao
nope. doesn't work.

Comment: Why not create a [mcve] showcasing the error. This way we won't have to guess, but will be able to pinpoint exactly the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: `<section>
    <template>` - it shouldn't be like that. You can't do this in HTML. `<template>...<script>` is pseudo-HTML for .vue files.

Comment: Anyways, your script simply exports an object. Are you importing this object and trying to use it anywhere? You seem to be confusing the SFC syntax (`<template /> + <script /> + <style />` with the browser syntax, where you need to declare components and/or Vue apps. Read the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started) on differences between the two.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to import it and use it for making a loop template and saw this script in other threads and simply tried to implement it and it doesn't render anything.

Comment: Here's how to make what you have work in a browser: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/6jucvha5/